# I hear coal burns hotter than wood. Can I burn coal in my wood stove, and just use less?

Tags: heating, woodstove

I hear coal burns hotter than wood.  Can I burn coal in my wood stove, and just use less?

I'd like to burn wood, too, but like coal.

Comment: This is probably also a legal matter. Your country may have bans or restrictions on burning coal because of how horrible it is for the environment.

Comment: I live in coal country (West Virginia).

Comment: That's actually a problem. West Virginia has "the high-octane stuff", that's even farther away from wood's characteristics than average coal. There's a whole game that coal plants do where they use Wyoming coal, but blend in just enough WV coal to meet their allowed emissions numbers.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, pardon my confusion, please.  If plants want to meet emissions numbers at the lowest cost, then they would minimize use of expensive coal.  Is WV coal (relatively) expensive?  If so, is that because it's cleaner?  You can see the direction I'm inferring from your note, but then I don't understand why it's actually a problem.

Comment: @donjuedo sorry, because your local coal burns even hotter than average coal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coal burners and wood burners often have a different design.  Coal is burned on a grate, with air flowing up from underneath.  Wood can be burned in a stove with a solid floor, with air coming from above and to the sides.

So if your stove has a solid base, then you may struggle to burn coal on it.

Answer (score 4):

Some stove manufacturers supply coal burning grates for their stoves, others do not.

If you do burn coal on wood grates then they sag or worse over time.

Comment: I've seen the sagging grates somewhere and wondered how they got that way.